# active comments in product category woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how to active comments in product category woocommerce and insert comment?

Exactly the same as blog pages that have the ability to insert comments by the user

I tested the plugins and codes that were introduced in Google, but I did not get an answer

Comment: Categories are taxonomies. Comments are only available for Pages and Posts , CPT's . Archive Pages do not support comments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need custom solution to achive this